# pysmb listpath method return error "SMB connection not authenticated"

Tags: python, authentication, pysmb

I'm using pysmb to connect a server (192.168.1.54) the code are:

```
    host = '192.168.1.54'  # server IP
    username = 'Test'  
    password = 'test'
    my_name = "localmac"  
    remote_name = "servermac" 

    try:
        conn = SMBConnection(username, password, my_name, remote_name, is_direct_tcp=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        return

    try:
        conn.connect(host,445)  # 
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        return

    bytedata = 'hello'.encode()
    print(conn.echo(bytedata, timeout=10))
    print(conn.is_using_smb2)

    for i in conn.listPath('misc', ''):
        print(i.filename, i.create_time)
```

the two 'print' codes run smoothly and the listPath function returned the error "SMB connection not authenticated". Why? if not authenticated, why the echo sentence didn't return error?

Any comments or helps are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1)  If you are sure that the username and password correct, check the version of pysmb.
I had similar problem with `pysmb==1.2.6`, so if you're using this version too, update to `1.2.8`.
The problem was with pysmb's own implementation of MD4 algorithm.
When there is no MD4 in Python's `hashlib` pysmb uses its own algorithm:

```
try:
    import hashlib
    hashlib.new('md4')

    def MD4(): return hashlib.new('md4')
except ( ImportError, ValueError ):
    from .utils.md4 import MD4
```

So if it possible update to `pysmb==1.2.8` where this problem was [fixed](https://github.com/miketeo/pysmb/issues/196).

2) `if not authenticated, why the echo sentence didn't return error?`  
The `echo` command does not require authentication, it just sends data to the remote server and remote server replies with the same data.